# Remove Duplicates in Nested List in R using Key Element

Tags: r, list, nested

I have a nested list videos inside this list there is key element "id" I want to remove all the duplicate videos from this nested list using the "id". Can some good soul help me in solving this ?

[image: Here is the Nested List in R]

Comment: try running `videos[!duplicated(sapply(videos, function(x)x$id))]`

Comment: Thanks this worked flawlessly very happy thank you again for your precious time 

Comment: Now I want to remove and filter this nested list with some word list that matches in x$title can you please guide me

Answer (score 0):

```
id_list = c()
dups = c()
videos1 = list()
for(i in 1:545){
  if (videos[[i]][[1]] %in% id_list){
    dups = append(videos[[i]][[1]], dups)
  }else{
    id_list = append(videos[[i]][[1]], id_list)
    videos1 = append(videos[[i]], videos1)
  }
}
```

Can you try this.Videos1 list will give you the list of unique video lists.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked flawlessly:

```
videos<-videos[!duplicated(sapply(videos, function(x)x$id))]
```